# Add a delay to a keyboard shortcut

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard, shortcut-keys

To put my screens on standby, I've defined a keyboard shortcut:

```
xset dpms force standby
```

This causes the screens to go into standby mode immediately. However, I'd like the computer to wait for 2 seconds before putting the screens on standby. How can I implement this?

(I've tried adding "--delay=2" after the command but this caused the keyboard shortcut to no longer work).

Comment: You could try making a script to run a delay and then the command, then run that script when you press the keys.

Comment: Hi @khpeek did you notice the answer? Please let me know if you manage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace the command:

```
xset dpms force standby
```

that you currently use in the shortcut, by the command:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 2 && xset dpms force standby"
```

It will work exactly as you describe.

Comment: What, no python? :P

Comment: @terdon oh shoot, I need to edit :)

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for your reply. The command works as expected when I type it in the command line, but something appears to have happened to my custom shortcut keys because it doesn't work there, and neither does the "xset dpms force standby" shortcut key which worked earlier. This is probably a separate issue, however.

Comment: @khpeek I think so, it still works here :). I will give it a thought, but I am on mobile currently.